# Error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in making histogram R

Tags: r, histogram

i'm trying to create a histogram in R.

Here are my data:

```
wealth<-c(100,150,200,240,300)
 age <- c(60,65,70,75,80)
```

I want the y axis to be wealth value and x axis be age

I have tried :-

```
hist(age$wealth,
 xlab="age",
 main="wealth")
```

but it says "Error in age$wealth : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `$` operator because wealth and age are separate vectors. Also, a barplot might be better for this, unless you want a frequency or probability plot.

```
> barplot(wealth, names.arg = age)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! and how do i adjust the axis in the barplot? i.e if let say i want the range of the y axis to be from 0 up to 1000? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at `?barplot`. You'll need to adjust the `ylim` argument.

Comment: by the way, this is probably the answer to the many recent questions from Coursera users about "how do I draw a 2-dimensional histogram of ...?" or "how do I draw a histogram with age on the x axis and wealth on the y axis?"

Answer (score 2):

As already said above, `wealth` and `age` are separate atomic vectors, and are thus independent from each other.

You might find it more useful to create a matrix or a dataframe to store your variables in, especially as the number of variables you have to work with increases. For instance:

```
> myDF <- data.frame(wealth = c(100,150,200,240,300), age = c(60,65,70,75,80))
```

Then you can use the `$` operator to construct your barplot, like so:

```
> barplot(myDF$wealth, myDF$age, names.arg = myDF$age)
```

Answer (score 1):

`age$wealth` means access the element `wealth` of the list `age`. Here `age` is an `atomic vector` (you created it with `c()`) so you cannot access the element wealth as it does not exist.

`hist` plots an histogram, i.e. a distribution, you probably want to use `barplot` to represent your data.